# Can I make my desktop icons smaller?

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, icons, gnome-classic, desktop-icons

I would like to make all my desktop icons slightly smaller.

I know I can do each one manually but that is impractical given I create and destroy about 20 files a day on my desktop.

I need an answer pointed at Gnome Classic/GTK3 (as in 11.10, 12.04, and onward)

Comment: @tachyons That's talking about interface icons (toolbars and whatnot)

Comment: i think that question is generic and difficult to answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm that was easier than I thought.

1. Load up Nautilus and head to Edit → Preferences
2. Under the Views tab, change the Icon View Defaults' zoom level.

That does only give you choices of 33, 50, 66, 100, 150, 200 and 400 percent scale so if there's an absolute method of setting the size, I'm open to that too. 66% is a bit too reduced IMO.

Comment: still custom icon theme is not possible ,it may neeed some hacks or nautilus patches

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively launch **dconfeditor** 
org ->gnome ->nautilus ->icon view 
then chose default zoom level
[image]